# cellForRowAtIndexPath not called from UISearchDisplayController delegates

Tags: iphone, uitableview, cocos2d-iphone, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

**EDIT:** Thanks for the answers below.  I couldn't get the `UISearchDisplayController` to reload the table, so I just ended up calling the filter methods when the search text changed and changing the array used to populate the table.

---

I've added a `UISearchDisplayController` to a `UITableView` programmatically as follows (this is using Cocos2d).  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is originally called when the view loads, but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not called when the search delegates return `YES`.

(`self` is a `UIViewController`)

```
    table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 80.0f, 480.0f, 260.0f)];
    table.delegate = self;
    table.dataSource = self;
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:table];

    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [searchBar sizeToFit];
    searchBar.delegate = self;
    searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
    table.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

    UISearchDisplayController *searchDC = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    searchDC.delegate = self;
    searchDC.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    searchDC.searchResultsDelegate = self;

//        [searchBar release];
//        [searchDC release];
```

When a character is entered into the search bar, the following delegates are called, `numberOfRowsInSection` is called, but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is never called.

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    // Do filtering and add to the search array
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:[[controller.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[controller.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:[controller.searchBar text] scope:[[controller.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: In first place, please do check that the results array for table is not Empty. Secondly, Also make sure you call `[table reloadData];` from search bar delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Check Following things:

1)tableview delegate & datasource are properly set.

2)In coming data in not empty.

3)check method **numberOfRowsInSection:** returning proper value.